# Isomorphism of algebraic structures as an isomorphism of relational structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

In connection with the question [Is a set together with an operation always a relational structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3057770/427611),
I am trying to represent an isomorphism of algebraic structures as an isomorphism of relational structures.

Let's say a *relational structure* is a set with one or more *n-ary relation* on it.
An *n-ary relation* on a set $A$ is a non-empty subset of the Cartesian power $A^n$.

Let's say an *algebraic structure* is a set with one or more *n-ary operation* on it.
An *n-ary operation* on a set $A$ is a map of a non-empty subset of the Cartesian power $A^n$ onto $A$.

Clearly, an *algebraic structure* is a *relational structure* with the following relations:

- The *product relation* is the *image* (a subset of $A^1$) of the map;
- For each element $p$ from the *products relation* there is also an *operand relation* which is the *preimage* of $p$ in the Cartesian power $A^n$ (a set of subsets of $A^n$).

We can define an isomorphism between *relational structures* as a regular *relation-preserving* isomorphism.
Then, we can say that two *algebraic structures* are isomorphic if:

- They are *product relation* isomorphic, and
- They are *operand relation* isomorphic for each pair from the *product relation* isomorphism.

Would it be a correct and an equivalent definition of isomorphism of *algebraic structures*?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're introducing several relations to handle a single operation. It's better to use a single relation: an $n$-ary function $f$ on $\mathcal{A}$ is replaced by its *graph*, the $(n+1)$-ary relation $$R(a_1,...,a_n,a_{n+1})\leftrightarrow f(a_1,...,a_n)=a_{n+1}.$$ (One major advantage is that the new language doesn't depend on the structure in question.) Really, this just takes what you're doing and bundles it all together into a single relation (you have an $n$-ary relation for each element of the image, this approach has a single $(n+1)$-ary relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *quite* have the right notion of isomorphism between relational structures; rather, an isomorphism needs to preserve *and reflect* each relation in question. A relation on the left has to hold iff it holds on the right.

In full generality - and this is the notion of isomorphism coming from **model theory** - an isomorphism between two structures $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ in the same language consisting of some relation symbols and some function symbols *(thinking of constant symbols as $0$-ary function symbols)* is a map $I:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ such that:

- $I$ is a bijection.
- For each $n$-ary function symbol $f$ in the language and each $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathcal{A}$, we have $$I(f^\mathcal{A}(a_1,...,a_n))=f^\mathcal{B}(I(a_1),...,I(a_n)).$$
- For each $k$-ary relation symbol $R$ in the language and each $a_1,...,a_k\in\mathcal{A}$, we have $$R^\mathcal{A}(a_1,...,a_k)\iff R^\mathcal{B}(I(a_1),...,I(a_k)).$$

Note that we're distinguishing between function/relation *symbols* ($f, R$) and the actual functions/relations in the structures they name ($f^\mathcal{A},f^\mathcal{B},R^\mathcal{A},R^\mathcal{B}$). This can often feel tedious at first, but it's important (although down the road once well-understood the distinction can be elided).

---

Now as to the "relationalization" process, you have the right idea but your implementation is not ideal. Specifically, your process for going from a functional language to a relational language is "structure-dependent:" exactly how many new relation symbols we introduce depends on the structure in question, so it's not a uniform change of language across all structures.

However, your basic idea is absolutely correct: you want to keep track of the "basic facts" of the form "This tuple of elements gets sent to that element" in a relational way. The right way to do this is via the **graph** of a function: given an $n$-ary function $f$ on some set $X$, the graph of $f$ is the $(n+1)$-ary relation on $X$ given by $$\{(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1})\in X^{n+1}: f(x_1,...,x_n)=x_{n+1}\}.$$ (Indeed, in the usual set-theoretic formalism a function *literally is* its graph, but that's getting a bit needlessly "under-the-hood.")

So in general we "relationalize" a language by replacing each $n$-ary function symbol $f$ with an $(n+1)$-ary relation symbol $Graph_f$, and we "relationalize" a structure in this language by interpreting $Graph_f$ as the graph of the interpretation of $f$. We then have:

> Two structures are isomorphic iff their relationalizations are isomorphic.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.